# CVAT shared annotation for all frames

Tags: annotations

I am new to CVAT annotation tool; I followed the instuction and install it today. When I start my first task and labelling multiple images, after I finished the first one and moved onto the second one, I found the labels are copied to the second image. When I tried to delete those labels, it deleted the labels on the first image. Could you please help me to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the labels showed up on all the other images; but I have tried to avoid any settings related to 'video' or 'interpolation'; I don't know why it happens

Answer (score 1):

Because I use track instead of shape...

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to your question? In the former case, please read [answer] and then [edit] it accordingly. In the latter case, please delete this and edit your question.